# I would like to create a code that removes a data series from an existing xy scatter graph on excel

Tags: excel, vba

my problem is that i do not know how to code in vba.

```
Dim srs As Series
ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
With ActiveChart
    For Each srs In .SeriesCollection
        If .Name = c Then
        .SeriesCollection(srs).Delete
        End If
    Next
```

it does not run.
sorry im new to this stuff

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
Dim s As Series, ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
with ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    .XValues = ws.Range("A1:A5")
    .Values = ws.Range("B1:B5")
End with
```